# In Vim 8.1, ":term ipython" gives a different version of IPython than typing "ipython" on an already open terminal

Tags: terminal, terminal-buffer

When I open a Gnome terminal in my Ubuntu 18 and execute the command `ipython`, I start an Anaconda IPython terminal version 5.8.0. Within Vim 8.1, that is what I also get if I first open a Vim terminal buffer with `:term`, navigate to the terminal and then execute the `ipython` command:

[image]

However, if instead I use the command `:term ipython`, I get a different non-Anaconda version of the IPython terminal:

[image]

Why would that be the case and how could one make sure that `:term ipython` gives the same version as is given by executing `ipython` on the terminal (in my case, the Anaconda one in the first picture)?

Comment: Could you please compare the output of `:echo $PATH` in Vim with the output of `echo $PATH` in the terminal opened via `:term`?

Comment: Do you have an alias for `ipython` in your shell config? Try `type -a ipython` in the shell window.

Comment: @Ralf `echo $PATH` indeed give different results and the anaconda2 path does not show up. I am opening Vim through a shortcut (`gnome-terminal --command vim`) and somehow this is making Vim to not get the system's PATH

Comment: Guess you manipulate PATH in your shell setup (`.bashrc`). When you start `gnome-terminal --command vim` via desktop shortcut etc, no shell is involved, so the PATH is not changed. You could try `gnome-terminal -x bash -c vim`.

Comment: @Ralf Yeap, I immediately noticed that. See the answer that I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ralf's comment to my question, I was able to identify that within Vim the system's `$PATH` did not contain Anaconda2's path.

This appears to happen because when Anaconda2 is installed, by default its path gets added to the `.baschrc` file, but that only affects whatever is opened via bash terminal - and I was opening Vim via a Desktop shortcut to Gnome-terminal.

Hence, a simple solution is to add Anaconda2's path to the Profile system's `$PATH` variable. To do that, open your profile:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

Add a line to the file like the following (but of course substituting with your own Anaconda2's path):

```
PATH="/home/username/Programs/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
```